# XIB with dynamic width, fix height in center - programmatically constraints seems not to work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

I created a .xib with freeform and implement it like this

```
if let alertView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(Constants.XIB.titleImageLabelThreeButtonsAlertView, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? TitleImageLabelThreeButtonsAlertView {

        view.addSubview(alertView)

        alertView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)

        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

        alertView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleLeftMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleRightMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleTopMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin]
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

  }
```

I call this code in `viewDidAppear`. The center thing seems to work, but it seems that the `trailing` and `leading` don't have any effect. I want them with a distance of 20, my `alertView` should have a fixed height and appear in center.

The xib has always the same size (see screenshots)

My originally targeted was to get a xib  that I can implement in every view for every device. So what is the best way to get this?

[image: xib file]
my xib file
[image: iphone 7]
simulator iphone 7
[image: iphone 4]
simulator iphone 4

Comment: I don't think mixing up autolayout and autoresizing mask is a good approach. Those are two different mechanisms that can collide and produce undefined results.

Comment: Thanks for response. Do you have a good idea how to realize what I want to do?

Comment: Instead of setting autoresizing mask, cancel it: `subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Besides, not setting vertical constraints (height or y offset) may also result in an improper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up auto layout and fixed placement (with autoresizing mask).  What you want to do is completely use auto layout so that the view will adjust its layout automatically.  You say you want a horizontal distance of 20, a fixed height and to be centred so I would do this:

```
if let alertView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(Constants.XIB.titleImageLabelThreeButtonsAlertView, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? TitleImageLabelThreeButtonsAlertView {

    view.addSubview(alertView)

    // Start using auto layout
    alertView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Set the leading and trailing constraints for horizontal placement
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

    // Centre it vertically
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    // Set the fixed height constraint
    let fixedHeight: CGFloat = 100
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: fixedHeight))
}
```

That will get you what you want no matter how the device, superview, orientation, etc changes.